# Conjure up or Appear

Tags: word-usage, collocations

I am looking for a word that can be used in the following contexts.

Example 1:

> Person A: I  moved to a new house since I began to work at a new
>   company. However, my old house had also a beautiful environment. It 
>   was  old stone house with a garden that has various flowers and placed
>   near a wood and a pond"
>
> Person B: "Your depiction ( make) me ......  my dream house in my
>   mind"

---

Example 2:

> Although science books can explain complex topics such as the solar
>   system elaborately with the help of pictures and diagrams, it may be
>   overwhelming for young pupils to ... how it works really. In this case, an animation
>   with narration would help comprehend the process better.

So I am not looking for a word that means " to remind". Rather, someone should draw a picture or imagine  in his mind based on what he heard with the help of his imagination. Which words can be used for this meaning besides "conjure up" and "appear", if they are correct to use.

Comment: In the first example "evoke" would work as would "picture."

Comment: Imagine and picture can be used as verbs.

Answer (score 2):

> **Brings to mind**

might be a good phrase to use in your examples:

> Your depiction **brings to** *(my)* **mind** the dream house I always wanted.
>
> ... it may be overwhelming for young pupils to **comprehend**/**understand** how it works really.
>   Animation and narration helps **bring to** young **minds** the complexity of the universe.

The phrase can mean either "***recalling***" an image or "***creating***" an image.

Comment: Thank you. Should we change the places of the words in your sentence because if pupils see an animation, they do not have to picture a system from scratch or  use their imagination. Although your sentence make sense , "to bring to mind" sounds like it means " to remember". By the way, is "conjure up"  correct verb also?

Comment: @Mrt Happy New Year! "**Conjure up**" is correct, but from my experience is usually used with magic meaning to "*bring forth*" something from nothing, like a magician *conjures up* a rabbit from a hat.  I suppose one could *conjure up* an image in one's *mind's eye*.